# Why doesn't my SpriteRenderer's color change when setting .color = new Color(166, 33, 33)?

Tags: unity, c#, sprites

I need to change the color of my `SpriteRenderer`, and so I looked up how to do it and come up with this code:

```
spaceOne.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(166, 33, 33);
```

(In case you are wondering, yes I checked that 'spaceOne' is correctly linked to a `GameObject`.)

This should change the color, but it doesn't. As I was writing this, I found that replacing `new Color(166, 33, 33);` with `Color.red;` actually does change it to red.

So now I am wondering, why does the `new Color(166, 33, 33);` code not work, and how can I fix it?

P.S. I made sure that it wasn't something simple, like it being RGBA rather than RGB, but no, it still doesn't work with `new Color(166, 33, 33, 255);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The `color` component of a `SpriteRenderer` defaults to white](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer-color.html). The [`Color` type](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html) is a four-component, RGBA, floating point representation of a color. The range of each component of that type is 0.0 to 1.0.

In your code, you're passing integers for each component, and all of them are greater than one. The documentation doesn't specify what happens if you do this, but there's a good chance it just clamps them to 1. So you're essentially just setting the color to white (which it already was), and thus seeing no results.

Try dividing all your components by 255.0f:

```
spaceOne.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(
  166.0f / 255.0f,
  33.0f / 255.0f,
  33.0f / 255.0f
);
```

Comment: This is slightly annoying, it's not great having to divide every time for efficiency and it makes your code less maintainable, and Unity don't make it clear in their docs! Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score -3):

I experienced the same Problem, but found an other solution:

`spaceOne.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(
  166.0f,
  33.0f,
  33.0f,
  1
);`

i forget the alpha chanel

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer OP's original question, since they explicitly mention that they tried providing an alpha value too.